# How to arrange monthly attendance by reading from attendance table using query builder in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have an student attendance table named `attendance_tbl` and is shown below.

```
id attendance student_id date month year
----------------------------------------
1    1               1    15   10   2015
2    0               2    15   10   2015
3    1               3    15   10   2015
4    1               1    16   10   2015
5    0               2    16   10   2015
6    1               3    16   10   2015
7    1               1    18   10   2015
8    1               2    18   10   2015
9    1               3    18   10   2015
```

I want to display attendance of each month together as shown below.

```
student_id date1(eg:15) date2(eg:16) date3(eg:17)
--------------------------------------------------
1              1             1            1
2              0             0            1
3              1             1            1
```

How will I get like this using query builder in Laravel 4.2? Can anyone help??

Comment: why you have store date in that way? laravel has a cleaner and easier way to handle date with timestamps.

Comment: will it be fine if this format is used ?                                                                   'student_id  date  present_count  absent_count
1   15    2     2'

Comment: Visit this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45995/display-monthly-attendance-report-in-mysql

Comment: @Alvi_1987 : I used this format to sort attendance based on month

Comment: you could do that by using timestamps and Carbon library easily. In this format you have to write complex queries and functions to acheive your desired result

Comment: basically you are arranging them date wise, so it should be like group by date as a single entity

Comment: @Alvi_1987: But if I want to view attendance of whole month.. then how will I sort it?

Comment: You can use MONTH function of mysql as MONTH('datetimeformat')

or you can install third party like carbon to do such thing to manipulate datetime format

Answer (score 0):

arrange your table in this format.

```
id attendance student_id date
----------------------------------------
1    1               1    2015-10-15 00:00:00
2    0               2    2015-10-15 00:00:00
3    1               3    2015-10-15 00:00:00
4    1               1    2015-10-16 00:00:00
5    0               2    2015-10-16 00:00:00
6    1               3    2015-10-16 00:00:00
7    1               1    2015-10-17 00:00:00
8    1               2    2015-10-17 00:00:00
9    1               3    2015-10-17 00:00:00
```

use Mysql function to retrive date/month/year
Now you can group by month/day/year in laravel query builder in following format

```
->groupBy('DB::raw('month/day/year')','DB::raw('student_id')')
```

hope this will solve your problem.